# How to update a dynamodb tables column with lowercase value

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

I go through some posts and came to know that in dynamodb case insensitive search is not possible, hence trying to update existing dynamodb table's column values to lowercase.
I searched for syntax but havent get any satisfactory result. In mysql we achieve same thing by "
`set name = LOWERCASE(name)`

Please help me to write same thing in dynamodb.
I wrote this query

```
aws dynamodb update-item --profile test --table-name test-event-tickets --key '{"university_id": {"S": "112"}}' --update-expression 'SET #nameAttribute = :inputScope' --expression-attribute-names '{"#scopeAttribute":"name"}' --expression-attribute-values '{":inputname":{"S":"george philips"}}'
```

but here i have hardcoded inputname to "george philips". instead of this I want to read column value and convert it to lowercase

Answer (score 0):

Unforetunately, there is no such syntax in DynamoDB. Although DynamoDB is capable of doing some transformations to data in-place, such as incrementing a counter, the syntax to do this is very limited, and lowercasing a value is NOT one of the things you can do.

So you'll have to scan the entire table, reading the old value of the attribute, calculating the lowercase version in your application, and writing the value back. If your application is doing regular writes in parallel to this transformation, you'll need to be very careful not to overwrite data that is being overwritten in parallel. You can do this with a conditional expression, but I think it will be easier if the new lowercase attribute will have a different name from the old not-always-lowercase attribute, so your transformation process will be able to write to the new attribute only (using ConditionalExpression) if the new attribute is not yet set.